# reverse only certain words in string

Tags: javascript, string, function, foreach, reverse

I am writing a function to reverse only words in a string that are a certain length, in this case 5 or more. I can make each word reverse if it is that length, but I am having trouble returning the right words back to the string.

```js
function spinWords(string){
  let splitString = string.split(" ");
  console.log(splitString);
  splitString.forEach(function(word) {
      if (word.length >= 5) {
        console.log(word.split("").reverse().join(""));
        return word.split("").reverse().join("");
        
     } else if (word.length < 5) {
        console.log(word);
        return word;
    }
    //should something go here?
  });
  console.log(splitString); //returns same output as when called at top of function
  newString = splitString.join(" ");
  console.log(newString);
}

spinWords("Jammerson is the best friend ever");
```

Alternatively, When I save the forEach() function into a new variable, the function is returned as undefined. I'm not sure which piece I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `map` instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

First off, your function needs to return a value. Also, try creating another string that will have the new value:

```js
function spinWords(string){

  let newString = ''; // added this here

  let splitString = string.split(" ");

  splitString.forEach(function(word, index) {
     if (word.length >= 5) {
        newString += word.split("").reverse().join("");  // added this here            
     } else if (word.length < 5) {
        newString += word;  // added this here
    }
    // add a space between characters, unless its the last char
    if(splitString.length > index + 1) {
        newString += ' ';  // added this here
    }
  });

  return newString;
}

console.log(spinWords("Jammerson is the best friend ever"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a little fix:

```js
function spinWords(string){
  let splitString = string.split(" ");
  console.log(splitString);
  splitString.forEach(function (word, index, arr)  {
      if (word.length >= 5) {
        console.log(word.split("").reverse().join(""));
        arr[index] = word.split("").reverse().join("");
        
     } else if (word.length < 5) {
        console.log(word);
        arr[index] = word;
    }
    //should something go here?
  });
  console.log(splitString); //returns same output as when called at top of function
  newString = splitString.join(" ");
  console.log(newString);
}

spinWords("Jammerson is the best friend ever");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only iterating the array with `forEach` you want to `map` it to a new array of reversed words:

```
 splitString = splitString.map(function(word) {
```

then the returned words will be taken. That could be shortened to this oneliner:

```
 const reverseWord = str => str.length >= 5 ? str.split``.reverse().join`` : str;
 const spinWords = str => str.split` `.map(reverseWord).join` `;
```